# Profiling java application

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, profiler

I have a problem with my spring boot application.
I have a rest controller that sends some http request by apache httpclient.

So when I load 1000 req/s to my controller I get answer after 1ms (in average)
But when I load 3000 req/s - I get answer after 3 ms (in average).
cpu load is about 70%

I tried to profile my application with jprofiler and found that increased time in ClosableHttpClient.execute method.

I decided that problem is that remote endpoint send data back slowly, but after some research I found that remote endpoint send data back with the same speed.

And now I don't have any ideas how to profile this testcase.

Comment: So? Looks linear to me. What kind of performance did you expect to get?

Comment: "same speed" as compared to what? are request concurrent or sequential? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Kayaman, I expected that my application would get answer with same time as my app don't exceed any resources (as CPU, memory or network)

Comment: @aled, same as when I load my app with 1000req/s.

Comment: You're profiling the _client_?

Comment: @Kayaman, I profile my spring app and in profiler I see that method execute of httpclient works longer